# Register before entering the main site

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

When someone visits my site and if there isn't any admin registered they should be redirected to that Adminregistration page.
Now this should ONLY happen when there isn't any admin registered whatsoever. So it should only happen when the database is fresh and empty without data.

I know I can put a check with a validationattribute on all controllers. But I find that a bit of a hack and well... The check should be completely removed when there is 1 registered anyway.
So is there another way to accomplish this?

Comment: What are you using to manage users of your site? If an administrative user exists is something you will have to retrieve form whatever user repository technology you are using.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a base controller that all your controllers inherit from, you could put the "validationattribute" you mention on the base controller to trigger the validation on every request, if that is what you want.

**Edit**

You could store a global variable in web.config called say AdminIsRegistered that is set to `false` when the application is first shipped. Then you change that value programatically when the first admin registers [like this](http://webdeveloperpost.com/Articles/Programatically-storing-global-variables-in-ASP-NET.aspx) and set it to `true`. Your custom attribute set on the base controller could then simply check that value on every request, as long as it is set to false, the attribute redirect the user to the registration action, otherwise it does nothing.

Comment: That's good enough for now. But it shouldn't trigger on every request after there is one registered.

Answer (score 1):

**The best way to do this is with a [global filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513%28v=vs.98%29.aspx)**.  You [register it once](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.globalfiltercollection%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) in your application, and every action that executes will hit the filter first.  All you have to do is add it to the global filter collection on `Application_Start`:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new AdminRequiredAttribute());

    RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

Comment: Your check for whether an admin exists at all can short-circuit the filter itself, allowing the request processing to continue normally.